# How many time can we measure the same entangled pair?

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, quantum-measurements

We know that the entanglement state is a very fragile state and it can be disturbed by very minimum interaction with environment, so how many times can we measure(spin direction) the same entangled pair before the decoherence occur and the entanglement is broken?

Answer (score 0):

Once. Its a problem with what happens after measurement. Take the entangled state

$$|\phi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( |01\rangle + |01\rangle)$$

After measuring the first qubit (say we get 1) we have the state

$$|\phi^\prime\rangle = |1\rangle|0\rangle$$

After measurement, the wavefunction is now collapsed into a product state, there is no more entanglement. It is physically not the same state anymore. If originally, $|\phi\rangle$ was a state that could be described by a hamiltonian, each part is now free to evolve on it's own, and will in general evolve differently than the previous state. By nature, measurement is a decoherent process.

If this were a spin relaxation experiment, the $|1\rangle$ state would eventually relax back into the ground state $|0\rangle$, and the $|0\rangle$ state would not be promoted.